# how to create a group of arrays from a text file with int values?

Tags: c

I have a text file with a bunch of int values, the first 2 lines have the value of L and C, then comes a space, after that a group of lines with int values separated by spaces, the first value is the size of the array I want to create with the numbers coming after. After this group comes another separated by an empty line from the preceding one, that has the same composition, but I want to save it to a different group o arrays. How do I read this file and save the values of L, C, and for the next 2 groups, How do I create an array per line?

ex:

```
5     
5     

1 2      
1 4    
1 4    
2 5 6    
3 1 4 2       

3 5 1 1      
1 2      
2 3 2           
1 2              
1 3
```

Comment: @aaronman: Why not use C?  Your response to "how do I accomplish this in langauge Y" is "use a different language"?

Comment: Something like this could be done in very few lines with a language like python

Comment: I prefer Intercal for this one.

Comment: @aaronman: That's nice.  Not everything should be written in a language like Python.  I wonder; what language is used to *implement* Python? Languages like Python exist because they are built by smart people who know how to use languages like C.  High level stuff sits upon a massive backbone of lower level code.

Comment: I asked because it would be much easier to do it in python, and not everything should be done in C to use your language, maybe he should do it in assembly

Comment: It'd be helpful if he told us what 'L' and 'C' stand for. And if he needs an arbitrary amount of arrays, not just 5 per group. Or if he needs to use these arrays later (for example, does L mean 5 groups? etc)

Comment: I am guessing this is an assignment question...thus C is a must :)

Answer (score 1):

You know that you can use a pointer as an array? And from that follows that you can use a pointer-to-pointer as an array-of-arrays. And you need two of these, one for each group.

Something like this:

```
int **arrays[2];  /* Array of two pointer-to-pointers */
```

After you read the first two numbers you can then allocate the second-level array:

```
arrays[0] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * first_number);  /* Allocate for first group */
```

Then after you read each line of a group you can then allocate the second level:

```
arrays[0][i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size_from_line);
```

And finally put into the numbers into the suitable sub-array:

```
arrays[0][i][j] = some_number;
```

Hopefully this should give enough information to implement it.

**Note:** If you need to reload this data, don't forget to `free` all allocated data.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **readGroup(FILE *fp, int rows){
    int **gp, counter = 0;

    gp=malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    for(counter = 0; counter < rows ; ++counter){
        int i,data,size;

        fscanf(fp, " %d", &size);//size of trailing
        gp[counter] = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));//+1 for size
        gp[counter][0] = size;//store size to top
        for(i=1;i<=size;++i){
            fscanf(fp, " %d", &data);
            gp[counter][i] = data;
        }
    }
    return gp;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int L,C;
    int **group[2];

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, " %d", &L);
    fscanf(fp, " %d", &C);

    group[0] = readGroup(fp, L);
    group[1] = readGroup(fp, C);

    fclose(fp);
    {// check print
        int gp,r,i,size;
        int rows[] = {L, C};
        for(gp=0;gp<2;++gp){
            for(r=0;r<rows[gp];++r){
                int size = group[gp][r][0];
                for(i=1;i<=size;++i)
                    printf("%d ", group[gp][r][i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    //deallocate 
    return 0;
}
```